# Python Flask web app hanging

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm very new to python programming, I'm trying to expose few terminal commands as a http call. I'm packaging this below code into a tar.gz using setup.py and extracting this on the server to run the code in nginx web server. once I instantiate the app.py code using below, the http calls work fine for few hours. Not sure what happens after that, the http pages show an error and I do see the app is running in the server. Can someone please help me with this

> gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 cstaradmin:app &

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask
from shelljob import proc
from flask import Response
from flask import json,jsonify

def get_pretty_print(json_object):
    return json.dumps(json_object, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=('\n',' '))

def read_process(g):
    while g.is_pending():
        lines=g.readlines()
        for proc,line in lines:
            yield line

app = Flask(__name__)

def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def help():
    """Print available functions."""
    func_list = {}
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if rule.endpoint != 'static':
            func_list[rule.rule] = app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
    return jsonify(func_list)

@app.route("/ps")
def IRR():
    IRR = ["ps"]
    g=proc.Group()
    p=g.run(IRR)
    return Response(read_process(g),mimetype= 'text/plain')
    def catch_all(path):
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000)
    except:
        pass
```

Error:

Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was    unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application

```
[2016-10-22 15:38:55,505] ERROR in app: Exception on /path/ToMy/command [GET]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/path/ToMyapp/admin/cstaradmin.py", line 42, in listnodes
        p=g.run(listnodes)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shelljob/proc.py", line 53, in run
        CommandException( e, "Group.run '{}' failed".format( cmd ) ).do_raise()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shelljob/proc.py", line 51, in run
        return self._run_impl( cmd, shell )
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shelljob/proc.py", line 63, in _run_impl
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, # needed to detach from calling terminal (other wacky things can happen)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1216, in _execute_child
        errpipe_read, errpipe_write = self.pipe_cloexec()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1168, in pipe_cloexec
        r, w = os.pipe()
    CommandException: ("Group.run '['nodetool', ' status']' failed", OSError(24, 'Too many open files'))
```

Comment: what error ? Gunicorn can save some information in log. You can use `logging` module to save some information in log too.

Comment: By the way, here is the error I get
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: add error messages in questions. Do you get any error when you run flask server without gunicorn ? Maybe it shows you more information.

Comment: same behavior even by running the .py code directly. Runs fine for few minutes and then enter into hanging state

Comment: @furas - added the full error message that I got from the gunicorn errorlog

Comment: There is `'Too many open files'`, `p=g.run(listnodes)`, `stdin = subprocess.PIPE` and `shelljob/proc.py` - so here is your problem.  It uses too many file or pipes  - it doesn't  close them or even it doesn't end processes. Now you have to read shelljob doc (or some tutorial) and find how to work with this.

Comment: `run(self, cmd, shell=False)
source code 
Adds a new process to this object. This process is run and the output collected.

Parameters:
cmd - the command to execute. This may be an array as passed to Popen, or a string, which will be parsed by 'shlex.split'
Returns:
the handle to the process return from Popen`

All the documentation I'm reading talk about popen for running a transaction. None talks of closing it.
Reference: [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shelljob)
[link](http://pythonhosted.org/shelljob/)

Comment: can someone please help with this? I know that files have to be closed. Not sure on how to do it. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: do you  really need `shelljob` ? Maybe you could use standard `subprocess`